# if-statement with string containing the condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

This question is about **Postgresql 8.3**.

I've got a table with a field containing conditions like 'lastcontact is null'. In code, I want to loop through this table and for each record, I want to check 'if condition then', like in this example:

```
FOR myrec IN
    SELECT * FROM tabel ORDER BY colorlevel, volgnummer
LOOP
    if (myrec.conditie) then
        raise notice 'Condition % is true', myrec.conditie;
    else
        raise notice 'Condition % is false', myrec.conditie;
    end if;
END LOOP;
```

The table which I have called 'tabel' in this example:

```
ID | Conditie             | Colorlevel | Volgnummer | Code | Description
1  | lastcontact is null  | 1          | 1          | ...  | ...
2  | lastchanged is null  | 1          | 2          | ...  | ...
3  | lastmodified is null | 1          | 3          | ...  | ...
```

Is it possible to do the check I desire? The code above results in the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "lastcontact is null"
```

---

***New section containing the result of Erwin's function***

I have used this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(lastcontact timestamptz)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  myrec record;
  mycond boolean;
BEGIN

FOR myrec IN
    SELECT * FROM tabel ORDER BY colorlevel, volgnummer
LOOP
    EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || myrec.conditie || ' FROM tabel' INTO mycond;

    IF mycond then
        RAISE NOTICE 'Condition % is true', myrec.conditie;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'Condition % is false', COALESCE(myrec.conditie, 'NULL');
    END IF;
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql' volatile
cost 100;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "lastcontact" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT lastcontact is null FROM tabel
           ^
QUERY:  SELECT lastcontact is null FROM tabel
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "foo" line 9 at EXECUTE statement1
```

I tried to find an explanation myself, but to no avail. It obviously is trying to run the statement against the database, but it should understand that 'lastcontact' is the variable that's been given as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments I finally think I understand. You need [**dynamic SQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(lastcontact timestamptz)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   myrec  record;
   mycond boolean;
BEGIN

FOR myrec IN
    SELECT * FROM tabel ORDER BY colorlevel, volgnummer
LOOP
    IF myrec.conditie ~~ '%lastcontact %' THEN   -- special case for input param
        myrec.conditie := replace (myrec.conditie
                        , 'lastcontact '
                        , CASE WHEN lastcontact IS NULL THEN 'NULL '
                          ELSE '''' || lastcontact::text || ''' ' END);
    END IF;

    EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || myrec.conditie || ' FROM tabel' INTO mycond;

    IF mycond then
        RAISE NOTICE 'Condition % is true', myrec.conditie;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'Condition % is false', COALESCE(myrec.conditie, 'NULL');
    END IF;
END LOOP;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Be aware, however, that this setup is wide open for **SQL injection**. Only use verified input.
A function works in PostgreSQL **8.3** as well (no `DO` statements, yet).

You cannot refer to parameters inside dynamic SQL (`EXECUTE` statement). You have to put the value into the query string.

In PostgreSQL 8.4 or later you have the superior commodity of the [`USING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). Alas, not in version 8.3. You should consider upgrading if you can.

I put in a workaround for your old version. You have to take special care of the `NULL` value.

Comment: It's not a table definition, but it shows three example rows. What if the field 'conditie' would contain 'lastcontact < now()'? The bottom line of my question is that the if statement should return TRUE if the variable 'lastcontact' which is defined in the code I'm running, is null, just because the field 'conditie' in the table contains 'lastcontact is null'.

Comment: The field is of type `boolean` as the error message tells us. So it can contain `NULL`, `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Nothing else, especially not the string `'lastcontact < now()'`. You try to enter a string into a `boolean` column. Not possible.

Comment: the column is a string. I get the string and it should give me a `TRUE` of `FALSE`. The string contains a condition. If I say 'if lastcontact < now()' in the code, it gives me `TRUE` or `FALSE`. I want to replace the code so the condition can be changed just by chaning the record in the table. I hope you understand the problem, I think you didn't understand it, my question might not be so clear.

Comment: @Leonard I think I understand your problem now. See amended answer.

Comment: You indeed do understand my problem this time :). Your answer might satisfy, but I'm using version 8.3 and the code is part of a larger function. Two questions: 1) Can I use this in version 8.3 and 2) what should be between the DO $$ en $$? My first try results in the error `syntax error at or near "DO"`. Only `DECLARE ... BEGIN FOR myrec IN ... LOOP ... END LOOP ... END` is between the double-dollars.

Comment: @Leonard: 1.) **Always** mention your version number in the question! 2.) The [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statement is for pg v9.0+ 3.) You can just put it into a plpgsql function, the body should work in v8.3. I amended my answer and changed it to a function.

Comment: My apologies, I should have mentioned it in the question indeed. I still get an error, but have changed the question post for a better layout of my comment.

Comment: Your latest edit made it work! Thank you for your extended patience and support! I can now finish the database part and focus on the other aspects of what I'm creating, which is more in my field.

Comment: @Leonard: You created a tricky problem. But it can be done. See my amended answer.