# Regex Replace in Postgresql 8.3

Tags: regex, postgresql, null, plpgsql

This question concerns Postgres 8.3.

I have a string like

```
NULL + INTERVAL '3 days' > TIMESTAMPTZ '2012-01-01' - INTERVAL '1 month'
```

Both sides of the > operator (which can also be <, = or <>) contain a timestamp or NULL, followed with + or - and an interval specification.

In case the timestamp is NULL, I want to get rid of '+ INTERVAL '3 days''. It should be possible with regular expressions, but I'm quite new to using them. How should I do this? A few examples of what I want:

1)

```
NULL + INTERVAL '3 days' > TIMESTAMPTZ '2012-01-01' - INTERVAL '1 month'
```

should be changed to

```
NULL > TIMESTAMPTZ '2012-01-01' - INTERVAL '1 month'
```

2)

```
NULL + INTERVAL '3 days' > NULL - INTERVAL '1 month'
```

should be changed to

```
NULL > NULL
```

3)

```
TIMESTAMPTZ '2012-01-01' + INTERVAL '3 days' > TIMESTAMPTZ '2012-02-01' - INTERVAL '1 month'
```

should be left unchanged.

Comment: Do you know that ```NULL + anything``` evaluates to ```NULL``` so you don't have to change the string if you want to use it in SQL?  Please also edit your question to fix the quotation marks as at the moment they seem a bit random :-).

Comment: I wonder if that's true, because of this error:`ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval > timestamp without time zone
LINE 1: SELECT NULL  + INTERVAL     '22 days' > TIMESTAMP '2011-12-2...`. I add an interval to NULL and it cannot compare an interval with a timestamp. Well, I added the 'timestamp' later, so maybe that's why your answer would be correct if I wouldn't have the TIMESTAMP. Anyway, `NULL + INTERVAL '1 day'` should be NULL when compared to a timestamp.

Comment: @Leonard: Tim is absolutely right, `NULL` combined with *anything* universally results in `NULL`. Don't confuse the **data type** with the **value**. You can only compare values if an operator for the involved data types is defined. This is just not possible in PostgreSQL: `SELECT NULL::interval > NULL::timestamp`.

Comment: @Erwin I'm focussing on the regex solution, because I'm modifying the string anyway due to the function we created yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893153/if-statement-with-string-containing-the-condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Expression could look like this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(txt
                    , 'NULL [+-] INTERVAL ''.*?'''
                    , 'NULL'
                    , 'g') AS txt
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
    ('NULL + INTERVAL ''33 days'' > TIMESTAMPTZ ''2012-01-01'' - INTERVAL ''1 month''')
  , ('NULL + INTERVAL ''3 days'' > NULL - INTERVAL ''1 month''')
  , ('TIMESTAMPTZ ''2012-01-01'' + INTERVAL ''3 days'' > TIMESTAMPTZ ''2012-02-01'' - INTERVAL ''1 month''')
    ) x(txt)
) y
```

Returns:

```
                                   txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 NULL > TIMESTAMPTZ '2012-01-01' - INTERVAL '1 month'
 NULL > NULL
 TIMESTAMPTZ '2012-01-01' + INTERVAL '3 days' > TIMESTAMPTZ '2012-02-01' - INTERVAL '1 month'
```

The [quantifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-QUANTIFIERS-TABLE) `*?` is the non-greedy version of `*`.

Comment: Thank you. I already used `.*` but it was too greedy. Why should we use the `?`? It does what I need :).

Comment: @Leonard: Cool. I added info & link to my answer.